# to_route() duplicate base path

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make my first application with laravel, but I have a problem routes.
whenever I try to generate a route (Redirect :: to_route () or HTML :: link_to_route ()) generated addresses are wrong. the base path is doubled.

this:

```
{{ HTML::link_to_route('admin.edit_newsletter', 'Editar Newsletter', array($newsletter->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-inverse')) }}
```

result link:

```
http://newsletters_app.dev/http://newsletters_app.dev/admin/newsletters/1/edit
```

**my routes**

```
// admin.newsletter Resource
Route::get('admin/newsletters/(:num)/edit', array('as' => 'admin.edit_newsletter', 'uses' => 'admin.newsletters@edit'));
```

Comment: Have you set an application URL in `application/config/application.php`? It might be a problem with Laravel guessing your base URL.

Comment: I don't set URL in config file, but if set, the result its the same.

Comment: Clutching at straws here, it shouldn't affect it, but do you have a <base href="" /> tag in your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because of the underscore**, the url 'http://newsletters_app.dev' is invalid according to filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL). Because of this, HTML::link() is generating a duplicate base. Solution is to simply remove the underscore from the URL.